# Kinect v2 pointcloud origin in real world

Tags: kinect, kinect-v2

For the Kinect v2, what is the location of the point cloud's origin, in reference to say some fixed, external feature of the physical Kinect?

For context, I have multiple point clouds taken by a Kinect v2, from multiple precisely known locations, but I can't get them to line up manually. (I've been manually moving the location of the origin around hoping it would just come in to focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be the center of the color camera as stated in https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dn785530.aspx
Hope that this helps,
Alex

Comment: per your source, the center is actually the depth camera.  
However, that does not answer where it is physically, in reference to some fixed external feature of the physical Kinect.  
Basically, if I know where the Kinect is, where is the origin/depth-camera?

Comment: yes sry, I read the document quite fast... btw is stated that "The origin (x=0, y=0, z=0) is located at the center of the IR sensor on Kinect". So if you know where the kinect is in the space you can just add the relative coordinates of the center of the IR sensor. To get the coordinates of the center of the IR sensor you car either open the kinect case or (easier way) refer to some papers they have already done this work e.g. Evaluating and Improving the Depth Accuracy of Kinect for Windows v2 by Yang. Hope this help

Comment: Yes, my question was for the relative coordinates of the IR(depth) Sensor. Didn't want to accidently destroy the Kinect by opening it.. Had not seen that paper before though, should provide a good start for me, so thanks!